# Http Request fails with response status code : 502

Tags: ios, swift

In a loop I'm hitting like 1000 GET requests. Since there are too many requests and the gateway  could not handle it, it fails with the error code 502. Whats the best way to solve this. My code as bellow.

```
 //In the array there are about 10000 ids 
 for id in Array {

  Network.shared.getData(accountId: id ?? "", successBlock: {(result) in

    //Save results to coredata

    }) {(errorCode:Int, error:String) in
        print(errorCode, error)
        
    }


 }
```

My Singleton Network later that ill be calling in the above method as bellow.

```
 class Network: NSObject {

 //These blocks catches success & failures
    typealias SuccessBlock = (Any) -> Void
    typealias FailureBlock = (_ errorCode: Int, _ error: String) -> Void
 

private static var networkCalls: Network?
private override init() {}

public static var shared: Network {

    if networkCalls == nil {
        networkCalls = Network()
    }
    return networkCalls!

 }

private lazy var configurationManager: URLSession = {
   let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.allowsExpensiveNetworkAccess = true
    configuration.allowsConstrainedNetworkAccess = true
    configuration.allowsCellularAccess = true
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60
    configuration.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 2
    
    
    let manager = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    return manager
   
}()
```

Inside the above class I use a generic method to call HTTP request (Here Im not showing the full method with all the parameters, but you can get an idea what it looks like)

```
   private func performWebServiceRequest(with url: URL, contentType: CONTENT_TYPE? = nil, requestOptions: [String: String]?,successBlock: @escaping SuccessBlock, failureBlock: @escaping FailureBlock) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = requestType // As in "POST", "GET", "PUT" or "DELETE"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

  let task = configurationManager.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data: Data = data, let response: URLResponse = response, error == nil else 
    {return}

           do {
              let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
                    successBlock(result)

            } catch {
                    failureBlock(0,errorMessage)
            }

  }

  task.resume()

 }
```

Comment: Best way to solve what? `502` is a server-side error

Comment: @mag_zbc  i was wondering if i could delay the request. but dont know how

Comment: You can check your API's documentation if you can get a batch of data for all accounts you need with one call instead of launching a 1000 requests

Comment: Nah its not possible as teh payload is dense. Is there away i could delay this newtwork call

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DispatchSemaphore` to limit the number of parallel running tasks, like this:

```
var countedSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value:500)  // Allow 500 parallel network calls
var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "runner", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent)

//In the array there are about 10000 ids
for id in Array {
    queue.async {  //(1)
        countedSemaphore.wait()  // (2)

        Network.shared.getData(accountId: id ?? "", successBlock: {(result) in
            countedSemaphore.signal() // (3a)

            //Save results to coredata

       }) {(errorCode:Int, error:String) in
           countedSemaphore.signal()  // (3b)
           print(errorCode, error)
       }
    }
}
```

The example uses a custom concurrent queue (1) to create tasks that will start the network fetching.
In the task, we first `wait` (2) for the semaphore. This call will simply decrement the semaphore's counter, as long as the counter is larger than zero. If the counter is zero, the `wait` call blocks.

After `wait` returns, we call `getData`.

In the success (3a) and error (3b) handlers, we call `signal` on the semaphore, to indicate that we've finished the network call. `signal` will increment the counter or wake up any waiting call.

This construct ensures that at utmost 500 `getData` calls are running in parallel

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand - what exactly is blocked? You should add some print-statements to follow the execution - before (1), before and after (2), before (3a) and (3b)